# How to log _bulk request payload sent by Logstash to Elasticsearch via output plugin?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash, elasticsearch-plugin

I am getting this error on using logstash-elasticsearch output plugin:

[2018-06-11T17:46:29,075][ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Encountered a retryable error. Will Retry with exponential backoff  {:code=>400, :url=>"https://myurl.com:443/_bulk"}

How to get insight why am i getting a 400 request? How can we enable logs for logstash-elasticsearch output plugin?

I am using ES version 6.2.2 and logstash 6.2.4

Comment: Have you tried to run logstash with the `--debug` command-line flag?

Comment: Yes. Still logs generated are for input plugin only.

Comment: in the ES logs, you should get some more output, can you check please?

Comment: What do you mean by 'ES logs'?

Comment: The logs from your ES server, i.e. the ones you can find on the ES server you're sending the _bulk request to

Comment: Is there no way to check it from logstash?

Comment: You need to log onto your ES host and check in the `/var/log/elasticsearch` folder

Comment: Generated error log using log.level=trace but not for success cases.

Comment: I don't get it. Did you see errors in your ES logs?

Comment: No in my logstash logs, I got status.code - 400 and status.content (error message) on trace level.

Comment: Again, what do you get in the log file of your **Elasticsearch server** not logstash? If Logstash reports an error, that error must be somewhere in your ES server logs, that's what I'd like to see.